# Selected Item Colour does not changed according the Theme Dark/Light

Tags: flutter, flutter-bottomnavigation, bottom-navigation-bar

I'm trying to change the colour of the item selected in the bottom menu bar according to the theme chosen (dark/light).
For example, I want to have the icon selected in 'black' when the chosen theme is 'Light', and in the other way around, having the icon selected in 'white' when the chosen theme is 'Dark'.

From **BottomNavigationBar()**, I'm trying this conditional formatting below, but this is not working properly (it shows on 'black' colour whatever the chosen theme).

```
selectedItemColor: Get.isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
```

Does someone has an idea how to fix it?

home_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container( 
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topLeft, 
          end: Alignment.topRight, 
          colors: [
            Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary, 
            Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary, 
          ],
        ),
      ),
      child: const Scaffold(
        appBar: _CustomAppBar(), 
        bottomNavigationBar: _NavBar(),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class _CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget with PreferredSizeWidget{
  const _CustomAppBar({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'TravelApp', 
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge!.copyWith(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
          ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true, 
        elevation: 0, 
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Get.changeThemeMode(
                Get.isDarkMode ? ThemeMode.light : ThemeMode.dark,
              );
              print(Get.isDarkMode);
            },
              icon: Icon(
                Get.isDarkMode ? Icons.dark_mode : Icons.light_mode,
              )
          )
        ]
      ),
    );
  }
  
  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(56.0);
}



class _NavBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const _NavBar({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      showUnselectedLabels: false, 
      selectedItemColor: Get.isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
      items: const [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.local_activity), 
          label: 'Activity'
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.hotel), 
          label: 'Hotels'
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.flight_takeoff), 
          label: 'Flights'
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.restaurant), 
          label: 'Restaurants'
        ),
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get_navigation/src/root/get_material_app.dart';
import 'package:get/get_navigation/src/routes/get_route.dart';
import 'package:travel_app/screens/activity_screen.dart';
import 'package:travel_app/screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'config/theme.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner : false,
      title: 'Flutter Travel App UI',
      theme: lightTheme(),
      darkTheme: darkTheme(),
      home: const HomeScreen(),
      // getPages: [
      //   GetPage(name: '/', page: () => const ActivityScreen()),
      // ]
    );
  }
}
```

theme.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get_navigation/src/root/get_material_app.dart';
import 'package:get/get_navigation/src/routes/get_route.dart';
import 'package:travel_app/screens/activity_screen.dart';
import 'package:travel_app/screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'config/theme.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner : false,
      title: 'Flutter Travel App UI',
      theme: lightTheme(),
      darkTheme: darkTheme(),
      home: const HomeScreen(),
      // getPages: [
      //   GetPage(name: '/', page: () => const ActivityScreen()),
      // ]
    );
  }
}
```

activity_screen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import '../models/activity_models.dart';
import '../widgets/custom_header.dart';

class ActivityScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ActivityScreen({super.key});

  static const routeName = '/activities';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Activity> activities = Activity.activities;
    
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          const CustomHeader(title: 'Activities'),
          MasonryGridView.count(
            shrinkWrap: true, // to avoid the error 
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), 
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0), 
            itemCount: 9, 
            crossAxisCount: 2, 
            mainAxisSpacing: 15, 
            crossAxisSpacing: 10,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              Activity activity = activities[index];
              return Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 200, 
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                     image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage(activity.url), 
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                     ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                  Text(
                    activity.title, 
                    maxLines: 3, 
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall!.copyWith(
                      color: Get.isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    )
                  )
                ], 
              );
            }
          ),
           ]
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar much with Get State management but I think you should wrap the navbar with obx so it gets rerender to show changes.

Comment: Alright, it's good to know. 

Where should I put inside activity_screen.dart for example (see above)? I tried to insert in at the very beginning in front of SingleChildScrollOverview() or before the Text at the very end

Comment: I actually found the solution myself:
- create a new bool variable under Widget build(BuildContext context) as following
(bool isDark = Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark; 
- when you want to change the color, apply as following:
color:isDark?Colors.white:Colors.black

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the solution myself:

- create a new bool variable under Widget build(BuildContext context) as following

```
bool isDark = Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark;
```

- when you want to change the colour, apply as following:

```
color:isDark?Colors.white:Colors.black
```